# Multiple postfix output IP

Tags: filter, message-queue, postfix-mta

I have a server with multiple public IP addresses.
I want to send campaign emails on this server.
Sometimes i would like to send mail from a particular IP (it is a filter on the sender email address that gives which IP to use).
The only thing i find is to install multiple postfix instances (one per output IP). Is there a best way to do this ?
I have a second question: Postfix gives a unique queue id to each message. If i have several instances of postfix, do you think thoses uniques id can be the same in 2 postfix instances ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[sender_dependent_default_transport_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_default_transport_maps) is your friend. First, add this to `main.cf`:

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender-transport
```

Next, create the file `/etc/postfix/sender-transport` with

```
@my-sender-domain.com smtp-192-168-0-1:
```

Any message received with sender `@my-sender-domain.com` will use the service `smtp-192-168-0-1` (can be any name) for sending. Don't forget to `postmap /etc/postfix/sender-transport` the file.

And then, add the service to `master.cf`

```
smtp-192-168-0-1 unix    -   -   n   -   -   smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=192.168.0.1
```

Again, the service name can be anything, but it must match the one on the hash file. This `smtp` service will send the message from the IP `192.168.0.1`. Change as needed.

Add as many services and lines in the hash file as you want. Don't forget to `service postfix restart` after that.

There are many other options you can add to the `smtp` service, like `-o smtp_helo_name=my.public.hostname.com`, etc.

I just finished to set up a postfix like this :-)